# Issues with setup of Coin-CLP

Tags: c++, makefile, configure

I am trying to setup [Coin-CLP](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp) that supports also CPLEX (which I have installed and is running smoothly on my machine) following the instructions found on the website.

Unfortunately when I try to run the configure step on the installation, that in my version where I want to include CPLEX as well looks like this:

```
./configure --with-cplex \
--with-cplex-lib="-L/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -lilocplex -lconcert -lcplex -lm -lpthread" \
--with-cplex-incdir="/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio127/cplex/include/ilcplex" \
--enable-static -C
```

I receive the following error:

```
checking whether symbol CPXgetstat is available with CPX... no
configure: error: Cannot find symbol(s) CPXgetstat with CPX
configure: error: /bin/bash './configure' failed for Osi
```

I have tried to search online and find similar issues and proposed solutions, but unfortunately so far I haven't managed to find any way to fix this.
So, any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've recently stumbled against this same issue trying to enable Fast-Downward planner to work with LP capabilities. I know this is an old question, but it is one of the few pages that show up when searching for this error, so I thought I may as well give my solution for it.

After digging through the config.log file inside the Osi folder, I found that there were undefined references to the functions from the DL (Dynamically Loaded) library, such as `dlopen`. So I added `-ldl` to the `--with-cplex-lib` configure argument. My configure call was like this at the end:

```
./configure CC="gcc"  CFLAGS="-m64 -pthread -Wno-long-long" CXX="g++" \
  CXXFLAGS="-m64 -pthread -Wno-long-long" LDFLAGS="-L$DOWNWARD_CPLEX_ROOT64/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/"\
  --without-lapack --enable-static=yes --prefix="/usr/local/" --disable-zlib --disable-bzlib\
  --with-cplex-incdir=$DOWNWARD_CPLEX_ROOT64/include/ilcplex --with-cplex-lib="-lcplex -lm -ldl"
```

Hope it helps.